# How can I add an event listener to the ReactJS Material-UI autocomplete clear button?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

ReactJS/Material-UI newbie question. I'm trying to add an event listener to the Material-UI autocomplete clear button, as illustrated in the snapshot below. I understand Material-UI Autocomplete already has onChange and onInputChange event listeners but I need to add a function specifically to when the clear button **(X)** is clicked. Any pointers on how I might be able to achieve this? Here is link to Material-UI autocomplete code https://codesandbox.io/s/97u43?file=/demo.js

[image: (X]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the Material UI docs with the [Autocomplete API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) the onChange event you have three parameters

```
...
onChange={(event, value, reason) => {
    console.log('event: ', event);
    console.log('reason: ', reason);
}}
...
```

With that in mind, the third one is the important for you, so the availables values are:

```
reason: One of "create-option", "select-option", "remove-option", "blur" or "clear".
```

use that validation to check if the user cleared or not the options

```
...

function onClear() {
    alert('you pressed clear');
}

<Autocomplete
   multiple
   onChange={(event, value, reason) => {
     console.log('event: ', event);
     console.log('reason: ', reason);

     if (reason === 'clear') onClear();
   }}
/>
...
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Vitor! I totally overlooked that in the documentation.

Comment: @sybercoda no worries man! we all do that sometimes, hope you achieve what you need :)